# Custom Highlight Failing on Website

Tags: javascript, css, highlight

I've noticed on a lot of sites with custom highlight colors, if you press CTRL + A, the default highlight color, blue, always manages to creep through.  Why is that?  In making my own site, I have my own custom color too, but I also have the same problem.  Does anyone know how to keep this from happening?

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/, http://www.admixweb.com/ are both examples of the CTRL + A problem.

Comment: In what browser? looks ok to me in FF3.6 and Chrome17.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not having any problems either. If you're talking about other elements with no highlight color set (or whitespace), there's little you can do about that.

Comment: @Andres Ilich, maybe it's time for me to update my browser, which is Chrome, but I haven't downloaded the latest version in a while

Answer (score 1):

Selection styles are mostly browser dependant, and might not be customisable in all browsers. Here is an example of how to configure such styles.

```
p.normal::selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color:#fff;
}

p.moz::-moz-selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color:#fff;
}

p.webkit::-webkit-selection {
    background:#cc0000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Such styling are very risky to use and **should not be depended upon**.

Answer (score 0):

Smashing Magazine is declaring their CSS `selection` as follows:

```
::selection{background:#333; color:#fff}
::-moz-selection{background:#333; color:#fff}
```

Hitting Cmd + A on my Mac yields the anticipated behavior in Chrome 12.